# mvn archetype:create SHA-256 MessageDigest not available

Tags: maven-3

This is my first time to try `maven`. My os in `linuxmint`.I have install maven successful.

> mvn -v
>
> Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
>   Maven home: /home/gzx/danale/environment/apache-maven-3.3.9
>   Java version: 1.8.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre
>   Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
>   OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-53-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

But when I have used `mvn archetype:create`

> mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.ch03 -DartifactId=simple -DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook

it showed a strange error.

> [WARNING] Error injecting: org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.DefaultPlexusCipher
>   com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:Error injecting constructor, org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PlexusCipherException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-256 MessageDigest not available
>     at org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.DefaultPlexusCipher.(Unknown Source)
>     while locating org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.DefaultPlexusCipher

It was so strange, how should I do?

Comment: Does it call **SHA-256 MessageDigest** when using 'mvn archetype:create'   ? But there is noting wrong of my java environment, and the version of jdk is not very old. So this problem is really strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you have already figured your problem. But I got this bug yesterday and I fixed it today. I should write my solution down. Maybe someone will fall this trap.

Actually this problem is because Java cannot find the class "SHA-256 MessageDigest". But it is provided by JRE default. It should be found automatically.

If you access your JAVA_HOME, you may find a file whose name is jsse.pack in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib, and there is not a file named jsse.jar. That is the problem. Type

```
unpack200 jsse.pack jsse.jar
```

(unpack200 will be recognized as soon as you have set your Java path)

and the problem should be soloved.

Note:
Some JDK's have jsse.rar not jsse.pack, therefore, running "unpack200 jsse.rar jsse.jar" command will get the desired result, and will not delete the "jsse.rar" file (in case of *.pack files, they get replaced by the *.jar files).

Comment: Thanks all the same! Your solution maybe work, but I find `mvn archetype:generate` are recommended and `mvn archetype:create` has been abandoned.

Comment: For me (in Java 1.8), I had no jsse file, with "pack" extension, just "rar" extension. Running "unpack200 jsse.rar jsse.jar" will do just fine. Problem solved for me.