# Message Digest exception getting in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am working on a spring spring boot project. I want to compile and build the project but getting SHA-256 Message Digest Exception.

I tried to solve this error but not able to find the solution. Could anyone help me on this?

## Code Snippet

```
  @Service
    @Slf4j
    public class CustomerFinancialProfileClientService {
    
        /** The feign interface. */
        @Autowired
        private ICustomerFinancialProfileApiClient customerFinancialProfileApiClient;
        
        /**
         * Update.
         *
         * @param customerFinancialProfileRequest the payment profile data replication request
         */
        public void update(final CustomerFinancialProfileRequest customerFinancialProfileRequest) {
            log.trace((MessageFormat.format("(PUT) Url: /rest/customers/{0}/financial-profile", customer

FinancialProfileRequest.getCustomerNumber())));
        customerFinancialProfileApiClient.update(customerFinancialProfileRequest, customerFinancialProfileRequest.getCustomerNumber());
    }

}
```

## Error Stack Trace

```
Error injecting constructor, org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PlexusCipherException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-256 MessageDigest not available
  at org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.DefaultPlexusCipher.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.DefaultPlexusCipher
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PlexusCipher
  while locating org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.DefaultSecDispatcher
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcher annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value="maven")
    for the 1st parameter of org.apache.maven.settings.crypto.DefaultSettingsDecrypter.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.settings.crypto.DefaultSettingsDecrypter
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem
  while locating org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingHelper
  while locating org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder
  while locating org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.Maven

1 error
[ERROR] Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA-256 MessageDigest not available
[ERROR] Caused by: SHA-256 MessageDigest not available
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41581834/5602214 Does this help?

Comment: well just gone through the solution. But not getting a idea how to approach to that solution. Need help @Prashant.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the directory where you have JRE installed.
2. Here you could issue the following command:
   `unpack200 jsse.pack jsse.jar`
   This should install the security extensions for Java and you should be good to go.

In Ubuntu based systems, just install the jar using following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libjglobus-jsse-java
```

Comment: Could you please help me with windows command how to execute it @Prashant.

Comment: I am using java 11 for my project .Java 11 version have only contain a single folder.        There is no jre folder. Where to execute the command unpack200 jsse.pack jsse.jar? I cant see any file named as jsse.jar inside lib folder of jdk 11. In java 8 ,jre/lib folder jsse.jar file is present. Could you help me with java 11 how to execute below command and get rid of the exception?